# Looking for fluid mechanics exercise problems

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, fluid-statics, education

I just started studying fluid mechanics with  by Faber and the book doesn't seem to contain any exercise problems. Can anyone recommend me a good source for fluid mechanics exercise problems so I can sharpen my skills and check my understanding?

Comment: I do not know if this is of help as this is a book about fluid dynamics. It has some exercises after each chapter and it gave me a good understanding of the topics.

A Mathematical Introduction to Fluid Mechanics, Alexandre Chorin, Jerrold E. Marsden

Comment: Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot